# Attain AES128/CBC/PKCS5 in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, security-framework

I have to place a call to a secure server that has following encryption requirements **AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding**, but CCCrypt or CommonCrypto libs that are available in iOS provide PKCS7Padding with CBC mode.

Any idea how I can achieve this encryption as server is third party and its implementation cannot be changed. I am using a custom IV.

Code for request is here.

```
NSString* exampleXML = @"<my xml file contents>"
const char myByteArray1[] = {
    0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,
    0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19,
    0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,
    0x16,0x17,0x18,0x19 };

NSData *iv = [NSData dataWithBytes:myByteArray length:sizeof(myByteArray)];

NSString* headPadding=@"GH12RT25Y2";
int* status=nil;

NSString* encryptionKey=@"FTH25GFD658ERT21YHU21==2";
NSString* base64encodedPass=[[encryptionKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]; // Base64 Encode

// Using NSData+CommonCrypto.h
NSData * encrypted = [[exampleXml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:base64encodedPass initializationVector:iv options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:status];

NSMutableData *headData =[NSMutableData dataWithData:[headPadding dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[headData appendData:encrypted]; 


NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl.com"];

NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[headData length]];

[myRequest addValue: @"text/xml;  charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// [myRequest addValue: @"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[myRequest addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[myRequest setHTTPBody:headData];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
[theConnection start];
```

Response says:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Couldn't parse stream.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: [PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 paddings are interchangeable.](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding)

Comment: The iv and key should be exactly the correct length (and the same on both sides) or there may be padding issued with them. But since you say: "unable to parse" either there is a data padding error (which should not really be reported as an error) or something else is wrong such as data encoding since there is no "parse error" in just encryption. Encryption is 8-bit bytes in, 8-bit bytes out, any bytes, no format. BTW, PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding are the same, it is just that PKCS7 is defined for longer blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if it works? In many instances the two can be swapped without there being an issue. Padding occurs at the end so if you get just garbage it's not the padding that's causing the issue.

Comment: If I encrypt it with AES128/CBC/PKCS7Padding its getting encrypt and I am also being able to decrypt it but server repose says unable to parse.

Comment: And just to check, you're sure the server is working correctly, you've given it some AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding data encrypted elsewhere and verified it can decrypt it?

Comment: I don't have any other test bench right now. Posted code. Might it help to get me out of issue.